# I had work done on my dentures, but they did not tell me the work was not coved by my insurance

Tags: contract-law, consumer-protection, fraud, tennessee, billing

I live in Nashville TN. I went to the dentist and had work done on my dentures.
They did not tell me that the work wouldn't be covered by my insurance, then handed me a bill before I walked out the door.
Legally do I have to pay the bill?
Also this was not mentioned in the treatment plan when I started going to them around this time last year.

Comment: How is the dentist even supposed to know that you have an insurance? Your insurance and what it covers is _your_ business and none of his.

Comment: Seriously - why is this tagged as "human-rights"?

Comment: every dentist I've gone to in the past 15 year has me sign a paper saying how much I will pay before they start wok.  A dentist that doesn't do this is scamming you.

Comment: @Greendrake In the US, the dentist will ask for your insurance details and take a copy of your insurance card. If the dentist is in-network for your insurance, they are generally required to file the claim, receive applicable payment direct from the insurer, and their charges must conform to the insurer's negotiated rates. If the dentist is out-of-network, they will generally file the claim as a courtesy, they may either be paid direct or charge the whole amount to the patient and the insurer reimburses the patient.

Answer (score 5):

You are responsible for the charges.  Dentists, doctors, etc. will file the charges with your insurance for you, but the insurance company decides what they will pay.  The dentist would have no idea in advance what your insurance will cover or not, unless you asked him to do a pre-authorization or coverage verification of some sort.  It's not his job to do it, but many will do it as a courtesy.

The dentist did work for you.  No different that any other service provider.  You owe for the work they did.  If your insurance didn't cover it, that's between you and your insurance company, not the dentist.